# Select multiple items from ListView with Checkbox using GetX in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-getx

I have a listview loaded from API using GetX. Listview has a checkbox so that I can select multiple list items. I can select list items and can add them to another list. But I am not able to show the selected list item (by changing the color of the checkbox to green) in the UI. If I use SetState(), I can. But I want to use GetX.

//My GetXController code...

```dart
class TeamController extends GetxController {
  var isLoading = true.obs;
  var teamList = <Team>[].obs;
  List<Team> selectedTeam = <Team>[].obs;
  var isSelected = false.obs;

   @override
  void onInit() {
    fetchTeam();
    super.onInit();
  }

  void fetchTeam() async {
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      var team = await TeamApi.fetchTeam();
      if (team != null) {
        teamList.assignAll(team);
      }
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }
  void selectTeam(
      {required String firstName,
      required String lastName,
      required int userType,
      required String id,
      required bool isChecked,
      required int index}) {
    isSelected(isChecked);

    teamList[index].isSelected = isChecked;

    if (isChecked == true) {
      selectedTeam.add(Team(
          firstName: firstName,
          lastName: lastName,
          userType: userType,
          isSelected: isChecked,
          id: id));
    } else if (isChecked == false) {
      selectedTeam.removeWhere((element) => element.id == id);
    }
    for (var element in selectedTeam) {
      log(element.firstName.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

//Page where Listview is placed....

```dart
Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 3),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                color: Colors.blue.shade100),
            height: 200,
            child: teamController.isLoading.value
                ? Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  )
                : ListView.builder(
                    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: teamController.teamList.length,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    primary: false,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                      return Obx(() => ListTile(
                            style: ListTileStyle.list,
                            dense: true,
                            title: Text(
                              "${teamController.teamList[index].firstName.toString()} ${teamController.teamList[index].lastName.toString()}",
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                            ),
                            subtitle: Text(teamController
                                .teamList[index].isSelected
                                .toString()),
                            trailing: teamController.teamList[index].isSelected!
                                ? Icon(
                                    Icons.check_circle,
                                    color: Colors.green[700],
                                  )
                                : Icon(
                                    Icons.check_circle_outline,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                            onTap: () {
                              isChecked = teamController
                                      .teamList[index].isSelected =
                                  !teamController.teamList[index].isSelected!;
                              teamController.selectTeam(                                
                                 firstName: teamController
                                      .teamList[index].firstName
                                      .toString(),
                                  lastName: teamController
                                      .teamList[index].lastName
                                      .toString(),
                                  userType: int.parse(teamController
                                      .teamList[index].userType
                                      .toString()),
                                  id: teamController.teamList[index].id
                                      .toString(),
                                  isChecked: isChecked,
                                  index: index);}, )); }), ), ),
```

The issue is Checkbox Icon is not becoming green unless I use SetState() which makes my GetX stateManagement useless. If there is any better way to use checked listview or any possibility to correct my code? Can anyone refer to any tutorials?

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `update()` function from within your controller when the changes that required a UI representation are made.

The follow function would be within your controller and be called from your `onTap()` within each listItem, passing the index of the the list item

```
  addItemsToSelectedList(int index) {
if (selectedItems.contains(index)) {
  selectedItems.remove(index);
  update();
} else {
  selectedItems.add(index);
  update();
}
print(
    'Selecting $index currently selected are ${selectedItems.toString()}');
```

}

Just to note, you might not need to add a `isSelected` to your model, as it is only used as part of the UI function. So, I would suggest that you use a `List<int>` instead to manage the selections.